# Rails Linking to an alternative view other than show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This is Rails 3.2

I have a list of visits and a button that I want to use to call a visit with an alternative view other than show . the button code in haml is:

```
  link_to 'Checkout', render('checkout'),  class: 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'
```

The button is in a visits view and the I have checkout.html.haml under visits/views

It seems like render should do it but it doesn't

How can I render a different view other than the default show

Comment: “I want to use to call a visit with an alternative view…”. Please explain what you want either using the nomenclature involved in the technology or plain language. What you're asking here does not make sense (a `visit` could mean an HTTP request, but you don't `call` it, and you don't pass arguments [e.g. “an alternative view”] to HTTP requests).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can `render` a view directly from a `link_to` tag, why don't you have a separate action for that link in your controller and then render from that action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render` i think should be called inside a controller action, i dont think you should use it inside your haml (view) code.

(1) your haml code should have something like
  - this link, when clicked will redirect to the `checkout` action of the visits controller.

```
link_to 'Checkout', checkout_visit_path(visit)
```

(2) in order for #1 to work, you should add it to your `routes.rb` file

```
get '/visits/:id/checkout', to: 'visits#checkout', as: 'checkout_visit'
```

or if you have resources blabla in your routes.rb

```
resources :visits do
  member do
    get :checkout
  end
end
```

(3) write your controller action for the `checkout` action in `visits_controller.rb`

```
def checkout
  visit = Visit.find_by_id(params[:id])

  # since we named the controller action as "checkout",  
  # it will look for a file named 'checkout.html' (for html request), or 'checkout.json' (for json request), etc. automatically (and the code block below may not be needed)
  # if for example you want to render another file, do this
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render template: 'some/other/file/to/load' }
  end
end
```